# 12.04LTS virtual kernel: no HFS/+? why?

Tags: 12.04, hfs+

Utilizing [Ubuntu 12.04 Linux virtual kernel [image: Install linux-image-virtual]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/linux-image-virtual) and it does not appear to support HFS/+ file system. Even after update/upgrade, manual re-installation of packages `hfsplus`, `hfsprogs`, `hfsutils` --- still cannot hpmount or mount any HFS/+ volume. `cat /proc/filesystem` reveals *no HFS support*.

By contrast, the 12.04LTS default kernel *does* support `hfsplus` after installation followed by update/upgrade. `cat /proc/filesystem` confirms that there is HFS support. mounting of same media works just fine.

So, I was wondering:

1. Can anyone confirm whether the 12.04LTS *virtual kernel* supports HFS/+?
2. If not supported, why not?
3. If not supported, when will it be fixed?

Comment: Just by reading your question I think this is actually intentional. The virtual kernel is not supposed to be run on actual hardware where you plug in hard drives formatted on Mac systems. Instead, the virtual kernel is supposed to be very minimal and fast to run inside virtual machines/hypervisors *in servers*. (with a very marginal use case for this) In case you run a virtual machine with GUI, you should be running the `generic` kernel anyway if I'm correct.

Comment: cat /proc/filesystems on the 12.04lts virt. kernel reveals support for many different filesystems. many SA's need to transfer HUGE files from other filesystems to (ext4) VM's. with the 12.04lts virt. kernel as it stands, one cannot transfer files from an HFS/+ drive. network transfer is the only direct option (without mod'ing the kernel or the HFS servers, which are not options in my scenario), and it's very slow, as is using an intermediary to convert. hfs pkgs won't even install. i find this rather silly and still need a soln.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the answer for future reference. Probably won't help you after so long.

The hfsplus driver is in the extra package. You need to install linux-image-extra-virtual.

One liner that fixes the issue for both up to date kernel versions and kernels managed by something like Ksplice / uptrack:

`sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-virtual linux-image-extra-$(uname -r)`

The solution wasn't obvious. I installed apt-file and searched through the packages contents. That's how I found the extra package.